# error #1006: value is not

Tags: flash

I am trying to create a simple word generator game for my 1st grade class.  I keep getting this error message, but do not understand the generateWord() message.

> TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.  at
>   COPYMakeAWord_fla::MainTimeline/generateWord()

This is the script I am using:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

wordGenerator.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,generateWord);

function generateWord(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    var prefix = new Array("bl","br","c","ch","chr","d","dr","f","fl","fr","g","gl","gr","h","j","k","kl","kr","kn","l","m","n","p","pl","pr","r","s","sn","sk","sr","sl","sh","sp","spr","sw","t","tr","th","thr","tw","v","vr","w","wr","y","z");
    var suffix = new Array("ast","awe","age","ade","abe","ape","apt","ab","ad","aff","ag","ack","an","ane","ame","am","ap","ar","ax","aw","eb","ed","ege","eke","ell","ele","em","eme","en","ene","ent","ept","ere","est","ese","ern","ert","eve","ew","ex","ext","eye","eze","ib","id","iff","ig","ik","ike","ill","im","ime","in","ine","ip","ipe","ir","ire","is","ise","ist","ing","ony","unk","ance","ull","all","ell","oll","ub","ob","ab","un","on","an","uck","it","ass","oss","orn","ard","ord","old","ot","at","ut","arm","it","ite","ive","iwe","iz","ize","ob","obe","od","ode","ioff","og","oge","ook","ood","oon","oof","ool","oom","oon","oop","oot","ooth","oonth","onk","ont","onth","one","ome","op","on","om","ope","or","or","ore","oss","ost","ot","ote","ove","ow","owe","oy","ub","ube","ud","ude","uft","ug","uge","uke","ull","ule","ult","ulp","ump","ulm","un","une","unt","ume","up","upe","upt","ure","us","use","ust","ut","ute","uve");

    var wordStart = prefix[Math.floor(Math.random() * prefix.length)];
    var wordEnd = suffix[Math.floor(Math.random() * prefix.length)];

    newText.text(wordStart+wordEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **newText** is a TextField, try this :

```
 newText.text = wordStart+wordEnd;
```

The error makes sense since, **.text** is not a function here but a property.